# Default response type get request angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http

I have a service like

```
getOrganizationsFile() {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/export`, {
  responseType: 'blob',
  observe: 'response',
});
```

}

and I call it in the TS file like

```
downloadOrganizationsFile() {
this.orgService.getOrganizationsFile().subscribe((res) => {
  CommonUtil.saveFile(res)
});
```

}

and I save the response and download it

```
static saveFile(res: any) {
const fileName = res.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
saveAs(res.body, fileName);
```

}

My question is in the saveFile method I pass res as parameter, I dont want to use type 'any'.

The response I get from the server is like [image]

is there an default response type in Angular, like 'HttpResponse' so that I can put a  type for it instead of using 'any'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default `HttpResponse` imported like this:

`import {HttpResponse} from @angular/common/http`

Read more about it on -> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own model based on what the server side is returning.

org-file.model.ts

```
export interface OrgFile {
  ...
}
```

```
getOrganizationsFile(): Observable<OrgFile> {
return this.http.get<OrgFile>(`${this.baseUrl}/export`, {
  responseType: 'blob',
  observe: 'response',
});
```

```
static saveFile(res: OrgFile) {
const fileName = res.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g, '');
saveAs(res.body, fileName);
```